# Подойдёт ли Rust для 3D игр?

Tags: rust

Сразу говорю что мне не нужно пока писать такие громоздкие игры как battlefield 4, gta 5 или saints row. C++ я пока не трогаю, мне 15 и я хочу написать средненькую 3Д игру который даже Питон потянет. Вот и хочу узнать, подойдёт ли Rust для этого?, какие кроссплатформенные игровые движки/библиотеки есть для него? Желательно под Linux(Ubuntu) либо Android.

Comment: Если вы задаёте такие вопросы, то вам Rust ещё рано трогать

Comment: Даже если это так, ответьте мне на вопрос! Подходит он или нет?

Comment: Для начала возьмите что-то еще попроще, типа редактора уровней или другой опен-сорс игры подходящего вам жанра.

Answer (score 8):

Это сложный вопрос.
Теоретически Rust идеально подходит для написания игр, так как он быстр и в то же время безопасен. На практике все существующие для Rust игровые движки в разной степени недопиленности, поэтому будьте готовы либо писать все полностью с нуля и тратить время и усилия на ковыряние, помимо самого языка, еще и принципы разработки игр, либо выбрать существующее недоделанное решение на свой вкус и контрибьютить в него для решения собственных задач.

Есть англоязычный ресурс http://arewegameyet.com/ , где описано все, касающееся разработки игр на Rust.

По существующим 3D движкам:

- [Piston](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston) - на данный момент наиболее разработанный, но и самый
  сложный и накрученный.
- [Three.rs](https://github.com/three-rs/three) - перспективный, но самый
  молодой из всех, многого пока не хватает.
- [Amethyst](https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst) - неплохая
  альтернатива Piston, тоже может потребоваться допиливание.

Также непременно приглашаем в [гиттер русскоязычного сообщества](https://gitter.im/ruRust/gamedev), здесь всегда готовы дать совет и протянуть руку помощи. Да и авторы некоторых движков здесь тоже водятся.

Answer (score 3):

Да, подойдёт. Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону [Piston](https://crates.io/crates/piston). Однако andreymal прав, если вы только начинаете учить программирование, лучше начать с Python.